# Some problems with View animation

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiviewanimation

I'm trying create animation on my View. Now I have any trouble. Animation is work only with _pageViewController

```
_pageViewController.view.frame = frame;
_pageViewController.view.alpha = alpha;
```

but _bottomImage.frame = frame1; doesn't work. I don't understand Why?
If I comment this lines

```
 //_pageViewController.view.frame = frame;
 //_pageViewController.view.alpha = alpha;
```

_bottomImage.frame = frame1 begin work.
What am I doing wrong?

```
  - (IBAction)share:(id)sender {
    CGRect frame =self.pageViewController.view.frame;
    CGRect frame1 = _bottomImage.frame;
    float alpha = 1.0;
    if (frame.origin.y==65.0) {
        frame.origin.y = 240;
        frame1.origin.y = 650;
        alpha = 0.5;   
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:5.5];
        [UIView setAnimationDelay:0.1];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
        _pageViewController.view.frame = frame;
        _pageViewController.view.alpha = alpha;
        _bottomImage.frame = frame1;
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }else{
        [self closeShare];
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm confused about something, it looks like you assign your _buttonImage.frame to frame1 then assign frame1 back to _buttonImage.frame in your animations.

Comment: I'm sorry. I fixed code in question. I'm trying change origin.y with animation. I want to move down doth elements. But it doesn't happening

Comment: Can you tell the parent child relation of _buttonImage ?

Comment: bottomImage locate on UIView. I create outlet @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *bottomImage;